# CakePHP belongsTo relationship not saving

Tags: cakephp

I have models 'PatientCase' and 'Procedure'. A case can have one/multiple procedures.

```
class PatientCase extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = 'Procedure';
}

class Procedure extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
            'PatientCase'       => array(
                'className'     => 'PatientCase'
            )
        );
}
```

I'm explicitly setting a value in my patientCasesController

```
$this->request->data["Procedure"]["side"] = 'left';
```

When i saveAll my patientCase, the case is saved correctly, and a new record is saved in the procedure table, with the corresponding patientCase id, however, no other data is saved in the record.

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you share the code where you do the saving?

Comment: $this->PatientCase->saveAll($this->request->data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment nailed it - `save()` only saves the main model, while `saveAll()` saves the main model and any associated models.

`save()` [[details]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array)

`saveAll()` [[details]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array)

**Update:**

Because it's "hasMany", you probably want:

```
$this->request->data["Procedure"][0]["side"] = 'left';
```

(notice the `[0]`)

Comment: True, but it's not saving the data into the procedure table, just an empty record with the patientcaseid and no other data?

Comment: Thankyou, this solved it, i didn't realise it was expecting an array of data (which seems obvious now)